# SSH: Why is my system offering my private key when attempting public key authentication?

Tags: ssh

Trying to connect to a server. I've received a private key to login to that server which I added to id_rsa. However the client keeps attempting to pass that as the public key instead of id_rsa.pub. Is this because id_rsa.pub isn't in my ssh_config file?

SERVER CONNECTION ATTEMPT

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
```

SSH CONFIG FILE (IDENTITY SECTION)

```
root@etoorlan4c:~/.ssh# cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

CONTENTS OF ~/.ssh/

```
root@etoorlan4c:~/.ssh# ls
authorized_keys  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the private key ? ssh can compute public key from private.

Comment: I copied and pasted it directly from the remote server. However running `ssh-keygen -i` returns `uudecode failed.` which the IBM site says means the key file is incorrect. I'm skeptical of the error because if I run ssh-keygen to make a new keypair, ssh-keygen -i still throws an error: `Enter file in which the key is (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): 
decode blob failed: invalid format`

Comment: From what (other than the potentially misleadingly named debug message) to you conclude your private key is offered? In particular, look for `debug1: identity file` further up in your connection log to see if ssh recognizes it.

Comment: `debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1`
there's no mention anywhere in these connection logs of id_rsa.pub

Comment: Even though your problem was unrelated, I want to reiterate what @Archemar said.  You can basically think of the public key as being embedded inside of the private key.  `Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa` means that it is offering the public key that it gets from your private key file.

Comment: SSH debug messages suck. Also see [What does “key_load_public: no such file or directory” mean?](https://superuser.com/q/962888/173513) on Super User.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The private key was invalid. A single character was missing from it.
The output changes as follows when a valid private key is used:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: root@etoorlan4c
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: sshkey.private
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:jmMyCOppv3KKkRgiHI4s5h3I7LwyCgms8uSG06KClQ4
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to [remoteHost]([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:22).
```